# Default attribute routing not worrking in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use attribute routing in my application. I provided the route attributes to all action methods and also provided the HTTP verbs to the action methods. But I am not able to set the default routing. If I manually provided the route in the URL, it's working but not able to see by default on application running. I used the empty `[route("")]` attribute for default.

Controller code :

```cs
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("myproject")]
    public class AttributerouteController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Attributeroute
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult Employees()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Employees/{id}")]
        public ActionResult Employeebyid(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Employees/{id}/department")]
        public ActionResult Empdepartment(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

My `routeconfig.cs` code :

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    //routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Attributeroute", action = "Employees", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tilde `~` on the method attribute to override the route prefix if needed:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("myproject")]  
public class AttributerouteController : Controller
{         
    [Route("~/")] 
    public ActionResult Employees()
    {
        return View();
    }                    

    [Route("Employees/{id}")] //http://localhost:12345/myproject/Employees/66           
    public ActionResult Employeebyid(int id)
    {
        //return View(nameof(Employees));
    }
  
    [Route("Employees/{id}/department")] // http://localhost:12345/myproject/Employees/66777/department     
    public ActionResult Empdepartment(int id)
    {
        //return View(nameof(Employees));
    }
}
```

By the way, you can omit the HttpGet attribute on the action methods. It is the default HTTP verb.

---

An additional useful information you can find on the Microsoft blog, here: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)